# Kubernetes cluster cannot attach and mount automatically created google cloud platform disks to worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, kubeadm, kubelet

Basically I'm trying to deploy a cluster on GCE via `kubeadm` with StorageClass supported (without using Google Kubernetes Engine).

Say I deployed a cluster with a master node at Tokyo, and 3 work nodes in Hong Kong, Taiwan and Oregon.

```
NAME              STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
k8s-node-hk       Ready    <none>   3h35m   v1.14.2
k8s-node-master   Ready    master   3h49m   v1.14.2
k8s-node-oregon   Ready    <none>   3h33m   v1.14.2
k8s-node-tw       Ready    <none>   3h34m   v1.14.2
```

`Kube-controller-manager` and `kubelet` both started with `cloud-provider=gce`, and now I can apply `StorageClass` and `PersistentVolumeClaim` then get disks created automatically (say a disk in Taiwan) on GCP and get `PV` and `PVC` bound.

`kubectl get pvc`:

```
NAME      STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
eth-pvc   Bound    pvc-bf35e3c9-81e2-11e9-8926-42010a920002   10Gi       RWO            slow           137m
```

`kubectl get pv`

```
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM             STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pvc-bf35e3c9-81e2-11e9-8926-42010a920002   10Gi       RWO            Delete           Bound    default/eth-pvc   slow                    137m
```

However, `kube-controller-manager` cannot find the Taiwan node and mount the disk to the node in same zone, and it logged (we can see the zone `asia-northeast1-a` is not correct):

```
I0529 07:25:46.366500       1 reconciler.go:288] attacherDetacher.AttachVolume started for volume "pvc-bf35e3c9-81e2-11e9-8926-42010a920002" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/gce-pd/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-bf35e3c9-81e2-11e9-8926-42010a920002") from node "k8s-node-tokyo" 
E0529 07:25:47.296824       1 attacher.go:102] Error attaching PD "kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-bf35e3c9-81e2-11e9-8926-42010a920002" to node "k8s-node-tokyo": GCE persistent disk not found: diskName="kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-bf35e3c9-81e2-11e9-8926-42010a920002" zone="asia-northeast1-a"
```

The kubelet on each node started with `--cloud-provider=gce`, but I didn't find how to configure the zone. And when I checked kubelet's log, I find this flag is **already deprecated** on kubernetes v1.14.2 (the latest in May 2019).

```
May 29 04:36:03 k8s-node-tw kubelet[29971]: I0529 04:36:03.623704   29971 server.go:417] Version: v1.14.2
May 29 04:36:03 k8s-node-tw kubelet[29971]: W0529 04:36:03.624039   29971 plugins.go:118] WARNING: gce built-in cloud provider is now deprecated. The GCE provider is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
```

However, kubelet annotated `k8s-node-tw` node with the correct zone and region:

```
May 29 04:36:05 k8s-node-tw kubelet[29971]: I0529 04:36:05.157665   29971 kubelet_node_status.go:331] Adding node label from cloud provider: beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=n1-standard-1
May 29 04:36:05 k8s-node-tw kubelet[29971]: I0529 04:36:05.158093   29971 kubelet_node_status.go:342] Adding node label from cloud provider: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=asia-east1-a
May 29 04:36:05 k8s-node-tw kubelet[29971]: I0529 04:36:05.158201   29971 kubelet_node_status.go:346] Adding node label from cloud provider: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=asia-east1
```

Thanks for reading here. My question is:

If it's possible, how can I configure `kubelet` or `kube-controller-manager` correctly to make it support GCP's storage class and the created disks attached and mounted successfully?

==================K8s config files======================

Deployment (related part):

```
  volumes:
  - name: data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: eth-pvc
  - name: config
    configMap:
      name: {{ template "ethereum.fullname" . }}-geth-config
  - name: account
    secret:
      secretName: {{ template "ethereum.fullname" . }}-geth-account
```

PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: eth-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: slow
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
```

SC:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: slow
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  replication-type: none
  zone: asia-east1-a
```

Answer (score 1):

After several days' research, I found that the reason is:

1. Master node is in `asia-northeast1-a` (Tokyo)
2. Worker nodes are in `asia-east1-a` (Taiwan) and other zones
3. [`cloud-provider-gcp`](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-gcp/blob/master/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/gce/gce.go#L352) only search the zone in one region (normally the master node's zone, but you can specify it by setting `local-zone` in the cloud config file), which means it can only support one zone or multiple zones in one region by default

Conclusion:

In order to support multiple zones among multiple regions, we need to modify the gce provider code of configuration, like add another field to configure which zones should be searched.

==========================UPDATE=========================

I modified the k8s code to add a `extra-zones` config field like [this diff on github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/compare/release-1.14...kigawas:release-1.14) to make it work on my use case.